# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC 4 with asp .net.  All is well until i get the error saying

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery'1[FYPManagment.OfferedProject]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[FYPManagment.Models.SupervisorModel]'.

I have search alot but still not working properly

**My supervisorModel is:**

```
public class SupervisorModel
{
    public OfferedProject offerproject { get; set; }
}
```

**My supervisorController is:**

```
public class SupervisorController : Controller
{
    DataContextDataContext dc = new DataContextDataContext();
    public ActionResult ViewProject()
    {
        var projectdata = (from s in dc.OfferedProjects
                           where s.FK_sup_ID == 2
                           select s);
        return View(projectdata);
    }
}
```

**My View is:**

```
@using FYPManagment;
@{
    List<OfferedProject> projectdata = (List<OfferedProject>)ViewData["projectdata"];
    Layout = null;
}
@model IEnumerable<FYPManagment.Models.SupervisorModel>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 AND
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.offerproject.proj_title</td>
        <td>@item.offerproject.proj_description</td>
        <td><a href="#">Send Request</a></td>     
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the variable `projectdata` is still a query expression of type `IQueryable`. It hasn't been evaluated/executed yet. The type of `projectdata` is different than the type your view is strongly typed to (`IEnumerable<SupervisorModel>`). That is the reason you are getting the type mismatch error.

First, update your action method to return the result of executing the query expression. You can call the `ToList()` method on the query expression.

```
public ActionResult ViewProject()
{
   var projectdata = (from s in dc.OfferedProjects
                           where s.FK_sup_ID == 2
                           select s).ToList();
    return View(projectdata);
}
```

Now make sure that your view is strongly typed to the same type you are sending from the action method:

```
@model IEnumerable<FYPManagment.Models.OfferedProject>
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
      <td>@item.offerproject.proj_title</td>
      <td>@item.offerproject.proj_description</td>
   </tr>
}
</table>
```